# Abstract algebra : distinct congruence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having some trouble understanding the meaning of a distinct congruence class.
What I understand so far is that when you have a degree  $n$   polynomial, then the distinct congruence classes can be written on the form $n-1$ degree.

I have been looking for a theorem which is strongly related with this, but I cannot figure it out.

Could you teach me through this problem?

How many distinct congruence classes are there modulo $x^2+x+1$ in $\mathbb Z_2[x] $
I know the answer's and the typical $1=-1$ in $\mathbb Z_2 $, but I need to understand why it is $0,1,x,x+1$.

Comment: There should be eight congruence classes, one for each polynomial of degree at most 2.

Comment: Ahh I forgot to mention that I would like to know why the list of them is 0,1,x,x+1

Comment: Do you mind explaining?

Comment: But that's *not* the list. The list is the *eight* polynomials of degree at most 2 (not the *four* polynomials of degree at most 1)$.

Comment: You seem to be working modulo $x^3+x+1$ in one sentence, but modulo $x^2+x+1$ in the next. Which is it?

Comment: Sorry, I was just looking at another example in my book. then could you explain to me x^2+x+1 I know that the list is 2^2 in this case, but I am not sure how we got these

Comment: Given any polynomial, you can divide it by $x^2+x+1$ and get as remainder a polynomial of degree at most 1. There are four of those, the four in your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distinct congruence classes are not $[0], [1], [x], [x+1]$, but $$[0],\, [1],\, [x],\, [1+x],\, [x^2],\, [1+x^2],\, [x+x^2],\, [1+x+x^2].$$

This is because of the *Euclidean division*: indeed any polynomial $p(x)$ can be written as 
$$p(x)=q(x)(x^3+x+1)+ax^2+bx+c,\qquad a,b,c\in\{0,1\}.$$
Maybe you're confusing with the fact that, as a $\mathbf Z_2$-vector space, it is generated by  any three linearly independent congruence classes, such as
$$\bigl\{[1], [x], [x^2]\bigr\}\enspace\text{or}\enspace\bigl\{[1], [x], [1+x^2]\bigr\}\enspace\text{or}\enspace\bigl\{[1], [1+x], [x^2]\bigr\}\enspace\text{or}\dots$$